# What is perfect code?

Tags: theory

I hear it a lot, and I have not seen a real definition.

I know it doesn't exist, except maybe in theory. But even in theory, what defines something as "Perfect code"?

Comment: The code that is not written?

Comment: @DavidBrabant true 99.9% of the time.

Comment: Cobol before 2000 was perfect. Programmers were retired and still needed and well paid to fix a bug :-)

Comment: I think the author is referring to Mathematics, there is a theory which talks of linear block code ,perfect code, convolution code and 
cyclic code on Math Wolfram it is explained http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectCode.html

Answer (score 5):

You may want to read this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)

Here are some quotes taken from the book itself:

> **Bjarne Stroustrup, inventor of C++ and author of The C++ Programming
>   Language**
>
> I like my code to be elegant and efficient. The logic should
>   be straightforward to make it hard for bugs to hide, the dependencies
>   minimal to ease maintenance, error handling complete according to an
>   articulated strategy, and performance close to optimal so as not to
>   tempt people to make the code messy with unprincipled optimizations.
>   Clean code does one thing well.

> **Grady Booch, author of Object Oriented Analysis and Design with
>   Applications Clean code is simple and direct.**
>
> Clean code reads like well-written prose. Clean code never obscures the designer’s intent
>   but rather is full of crisp abstractions and straightforward lines of control.

> **“Big” Dave Thomas, founder of OTI, godfather of the Eclipse strategy**
>
> Clean code can be read, and enhanced by a developer other than its
>   original author. It has unit and acceptance tests. It has meaningful
>   names. It provides one way rather than many ways for doing one thing.
>   It has minimal dependencies, which are explicitly defined, and
>   provides a clear and minimal API. Code should be literate since
>   depending on the language, not all necessary information can be
>   expressed clearly in code alone.

> **Michael Feathers, author of Working Effectively with Legacy Code**
>
> I could list all of the qualities that I
>   notice in clean code, but there is one overarching quality that leads
>   to all of them. Clean code always looks like it was written by someone
>   who cares. There is nothing obvious that you can do to make it better.
>   All of those things were thought about by the code’s author, and if
>   you try to imagine improvements, you’re led back to where you are,
>   sitting in appreciation of the code someone left for you—code left by
>   someone who cares deeply about the craft.

> **Ron Jeffries, author of Extreme Programming
>   Installed and Extreme Programming
>   Adventures in C#**
>
> In recent years I begin, and nearly end, with Beck’s
>   rules of simple code. In priority order, simple code:
>
> - Runs all the tests;
> - Contains no duplication;
> - Expresses all the design ideas that are in the system;
> - Minimizes the number of entities such as classes, methods, functions, and the like.
>
> Of these, I focus mostly on
>   duplication. When the same thing is done over and over, it’s a sign
>   that there is an idea in our mind that is not well represented in the
>   code. I try to figure out what it is. Then I try to express that idea
>   more clearly.
>
> Expressiveness to me includes meaningful names, and I am
>   likely to change the names of things several times before I settle in.
>   With modern coding tools such as Eclipse, renaming is quite
>   inexpensive, so it doesn’t trouble me to change. Expressiveness goes
>   The Total Cost of Owning a Mess 11 beyond names, however. I also look
>   at whether an object or method is doing more than one thing. If it’s
>   an object, it probably needs to be broken into two or more objects. If
>   it’s a method, I will always use the Extract Method refactoring on it,
>   resulting in one method that says more clearly what it does, and some
>   submethods saying how it is done.
>
> Duplication and expressiveness take
>   me a very long way into what I consider clean code, and improving
>   dirty code with just these two things in mind can make a huge
>   difference. There is, however, one other thing that I’m aware of
>   doing, which is a bit harder to explain.
>
> After years of doing this
>   work, it seems to me that all programs are made up of very similar
>   elements. One example is “find things in a collection.” Whether we
>   have a database of employee records, or a hash map of keys and values,
>   or an array of items of some kind, we often find ourselves wanting a
>   particular item from that collection. When I find that happening, I
>   will often wrap the particular implementation in a more abstract
>   method or class. That gives me a couple of interesting advantages.
>
> I can implement the functionality now with something simple, say a hash
>   map, but since now all the references to that search are covered by my
>   little abstraction, I can change the implementation any time I want. I
>   can go forward quickly while preserving my ability to change later.
>
> In
>   addition, the collection abstraction often calls my attention to
>   what’s “really” going on, and keeps me from running down the path of
>   implementing arbitrary collection behavior when all I really need is a
>   few fairly simple ways of finding what I want.
>
> Reduced duplication,
>   high expressiveness, and early building of simple abstractions. That’s
>   what makes clean code for me.

> **Ward Cunningham, inventor of Wiki,
>   inventor of Fit, coinventor of eXtreme Programming. Motive force
>   behind Design Patterns. Smalltalk and OO thought leader. The godfather
>   of all those who care about code.**
>
> You know you are working on clean code when each
>   routine you read turns out to be pretty much what you expected. You
>   can call it beautiful code when the code also makes it look like the
>   language was made for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My list in no particular order

- It does what is required
- It does it correctly, predictably and securely
- It is easy for others to understand and maintain
- It is well documented
- If/when it fails, it gives meaningful error messages
- It doesn't try to be needlessly clever

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that there is no perfect code.But every Code must be organized with proper class/variable/function names,proper indentation,proper comments,proper algorithm or we can say correct algorithm, and good memory management.

Comment: So, a "near perfect code" would be possible; just not a perfect one. We discussed "perfect code" in IRC, but even a simple hello world program would be imperfect because "What if they user doesn't speak language x"? Suddenly, you have to design this program that supports every language to say "Hello World", this brings about the need of an interface to select the language. Saying "Hello World" suddenly becomes a scary, large, and bug-ridden task.